# How to escape the "." reserved symbol when using an input for an sql script

Tags: sql, oracle

I pass on a variable as an input to a sql script from a .bat. This is an example from the sql script:

```
  CREATE TABLE &1.TABLEX
(X          NUMBER(25,0),
 Y          VARCHAR2(250),
 Z          VARCHAR2(250),
 CONSTRAINT PK_X PRIMARY KEY (X))
 NOLOGGING
 TABLESPACE &1;
```

The problem is "&1.TABLEX" The "." is reserved in sql scripts to terminate a variable name. All i want is to append a "." between the input &1 and TABLEX. How can i achieve this? I have tried [], `` and "" to no avail.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use double period `&1..TABLEX`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While i waited for an answer i found the following solutions:

```
    "set define off" and using \.
```

OR

```
    "set escape ON" and using .
```

And turning the properties to its default value after using them. I ended up using Nicholas Krasnov's solution of using a "&1..TABLEX" because it didnt require any property change. Thank you!